# @Controller Kafka Listener exception not catched by Exception handler @ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka Listener marked with `@Controller`:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${binlookup.kafka.topic.insert}")
public BinInfoJsonDTO listenAndInsert(String binInfoJson, Acknowledgment ack) {
    log.debug("Kafka server: {}", bootstrapServers);
    log.info("Kafka inserting: {}", binInfoJson);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    BinInfoJsonDTO dto;
    BinLookupError error;
    String responseError;
    try {
        dto = mapper.readValue(binInfoJson, BinInfoJsonDTO.class);    // <--- exception happens here
        log.debug("The converted DTO: {}", dto);
        ResponseEntity<BinInfoJsonDTO> response = controller.insertBIN(Utilities.jsonDtoToEntity(dto));
        log.debug("BIN inserted by Kafka. {}", response);
        if (response.getStatusCodeValue() == HttpStatus.OK.value() ||
                response.getStatusCodeValue() == HttpStatus.CREATED.value()) {
            ack.acknowledge(); // manual acknowledge.
            log.debug("Acknowledged.");
        } else {
            responseError = "Unexpected response status code: " + response.getStatusCodeValue();
            log.error(responseError);
            error = new BinLookupError(responseError);
            error.setErrorType(ErrorTypeEnum.UNEXPECTED_STATUS_CODE);
            throw new BinLookupException(error);
        }
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.error("Cannot parse Kafka incoming JSON. ", e);
        error = new BinLookupError(e.getMessage());
        error.setErrorType(ErrorTypeEnum.KAFKA_JSON_FAILURE);
        throw new BinLookupException(error);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        log.error("I/O exception in Kafka. ", e1);
        error = new BinLookupError(e1.getMessage());
        error.setErrorType(ErrorTypeEnum.IO_EXCEPTION);
        throw new BinLookupException(error);
    }

    return dto;
}
```

And, I have an exception handler marked with `@ControllerAdvice`:

```
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
public class BinLookupExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {BinLookupException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<BinLookupError> handleBinLookupException(BinLookupException ex) {
        BinLookupError error = ex.getError();
        log.error("Exception handler: {}", error.getOriginalMsg());
        ...


}
```

Now, when I run the application and enter wrongly formatted JSON into the producer, the exception will occur but not catched by the exception handler. The exception is `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException`.

```
[NODE=Shenmue3] [ENV=dev] [SRC=UNDEFINED] [TRACE=] [SPAN=] [2018-09-13T09:38:21.035Z] [INFO] [MSG=[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] c.p.binlookup.kafka.BinInfoConsumer - Kafka inserting: {{{{{ ]
[NODE=Shenmue3] [ENV=dev] [SRC=UNDEFINED] [TRACE=] [SPAN=] [2018-09-13T09:38:21.119Z] [ERROR] [MSG=[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] c.p.binlookup.kafka.BinInfoConsumer - Cannot parse Kafka incoming JSON.  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{{{{{"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:561)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1757)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:682)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2992)
    at com.xxx.binlookup.kafka.BinInfoConsumer.listenAndInsert(BinInfoConsumer.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:248)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:998)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:866)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:724)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]
[NODE=Shenmue3] [ENV=dev] [SRC=UNDEFINED] [TRACE=] [SPAN=] [2018-09-13T09:38:21.122Z] [ERROR] [MSG=[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] o.s.k.listener.LoggingErrorHandler - Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = insert, partition = 0, offset = 0, CreateTime = 1536831499778, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 5, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = {{{{{) org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public com.xxx.binlookup.dto.BinInfoJsonDTO com.xxx.binlookup.kafka.BinInfoConsumer.listenAndInsert(java.lang.String,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment)' threw exception; nested exception is BinLookupException [error=BinLookupError(originalMsg=Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{{{{{"; line: 1, column: 3], fields=[], errorType=Cannot parse Kafka incoming JSON)]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:267)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:998)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:866)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:724)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.xxx.binlookup.exception.BinLookupException: Original message is: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{{{{{"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.xxx.binlookup.kafka.BinInfoConsumer.listenAndInsert(BinInfoConsumer.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:248)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
]
```

`"Exception handler: {}"`, as part of the log in the handler, is not there.

What more should I do to make it aware of my exception thrown? Thanks.

Comment: `@ControllerAdvice` is for controllers and annotating a `@KafkaListerner` annotated class with `@Controller` doesn't make sense. I don't think you can catch exceptions from `@KafkaListener` in `@ExceptionHandler`

Comment: Since @ExceptionHandler is used for catching the exceptions which occur as part of any request to controller endpoint, and returns the response to the http(s) request, it cannot be used for `@KafkaListener` since it's not a request through your controller endpoint.

Comment: OK... so there is no way to handler the Kafka exceptions in a application-wide way? Just curious.

Comment: Spring kafka provides the ErrorHandler interface to handle all exceptions. You can read more on that here https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#annotation-error-handling

Comment: If you are using Spring 2.x, @KafkaListener has a `errorHandler` attribute that can help you configure the errorHandler

Comment: For Spring 1.x, you would need to add your errorHandler to the KafkaListenerContainerFactory Bean. All that is specified in the Spring documentation that I have shared in the previous comment.

Comment: Did this help @WesternGun?

Comment: Yes definitely. Thank you very much. I see the `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` returns `Object`; will the return value be processed somewhere?

Comment: @MadhuBhat, The link is broken. Could you please update the new link if you have that handy?

Comment: @Clover Yeah sure, it is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling). Just the `htmlsingle` was changed to `html` in their docs link.